# Is there a way to remove the "Add Image" button of AssetManager of grapesjs editor in a vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, grapesjs

I want to remove the Add Image button and its textbox. Is there a way to do it, by setting the configuration of assetManager or by some other way ?

[image: grapesjs image upload]

```
 this.editor = new grapesjsEditor.init({
      container: this.forGrapesjs,
      components: this.value,
      assetManager: {
        embedAsBase64: 1,
        uploadText: 'Drag file here or upload',
        upload: 0
      }
    });
```

Please look into the assetManager configuration. I have set it to upload 0 which is false.

Comment: Where is the code which you tried so far ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the css classes? If they are unique you can overwrite them. If they are not you still have the possibility of creating your own unique css selector selecting these buttons. Setting `display: none` will remove them from the DOM.

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat Thanks for your suggestion. I have set the visibility as hidden for the button and textbox. I have posted the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You may also add other classes to resize the gray area to fit the drop box.

Comment: okay. Would look into it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hidden the "Add Image" button and its path URL textbox using css styling.

```
.gjs-am-add-asset .gjs-am-add-field{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.gjs-am-add-asset button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

And imported the css into the vue component.

```
import './style.css';
```

[image: Upload Image]